# Custom edit Panel/Tab for content type

Tags: nodes

In Drupal 8 I have a custom content type, and I want to add a group of fields to it that are related to tracking. Since these fields don't have to do with the content displayed, I wanted to separate these options in the UI by having them on a different tab or panel.

This is an example of what I have in mind.

[image: screenshot]

What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there some hook to achieve this?

I have done a lot of searching, but I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: Have you tried clicking 'Add Group' and then choosing 'Tabs'   on the 'Manage form display'  section of the content type editing page?

Comment: @Matt TY for the response - If i go to /admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields I don't see any option to add a group for my stock instance of Drupal 8. I only see "Add field" and group / tab is nowhere in that list.

Comment: Hmm must be a module I installed that added that functionality. I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Found it. Added it as an answer. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field Group is a module that provides this functionality.
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group